# Как обновлять данные в локальном БД при изменении БД на сервере?

Tags: java, android, realm

Я использую на стороне клиента: `Retrofit 2, Realm`. Клиент парсит `JSON` и ложит их в локальную БД `Realm` и после этого отображает их в `RecyclerView`.

Я реализовал метод парсинга `JSON'a` в методе `onCreate`, с проверкой на то, пустая ли локальная база данных, и если пустая - то клиент парсит `JSON` с сервера и загружает их в базу, но если база не пустая - то клиент берет данные из локальной БД и отображает их.

Этот способ не работает при обновлении информации на сервере. Если нужно обновить информацию - мне приходится удалять приложение и устанавливать заново, чтобы БД очистилась и клиент скачал всю информацию с сервера заново.

Мне нужно чтобы при изменении информации на серверной БД клиент как-то узнавал об этом и скачивал данные ТОЛЬКО изменения после перезагрузки приложения.
Как это реализовать? С помощью чего? Можете дать ссылки на туториалы, что реализовать такое?

Comment: если сервер должен сообщать клиенту - то тебе надо копать в сторону пуш уведомлений. минимальное решение - открываешь активити/фрагмент который отображает данные, в этот момент первым делом подругжаешь с локальной базы и в фоне идешь на сервер за новыми данными, пишешь в локалку и обновляешь интерфейс. т.е. ты сам стучишь на сервер, когда тебе надо показать данные.

Comment: т.е всю информацию каждый раз нужно будет заново загружать?

Comment: Можно просто использовать [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) и не изобретать велосипед.

Comment: У Realm есть [Realm Mobile Platform](https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-platform/). Т.е. реалм работает и на сервере и на клиенте (к примеру, в Андроид приложении). Синхронизация проходит автоматически, т.е. если вы что-то сохранили на клиенте - изменения произойдут и на сервере и наоборот. Но эта штука не бесплатная :)

Answer (score 3):

Общая схема может быть следующая:

При первом запуске приложения запрашиваете все данные и сохраняете локально. Также сохраняете текущее время. Оно и будет временем последнего обновления. При следующих запусках отправляете время последнего обновления. Сервер проверяет, появились ли с этого времени новые данные и если есть, возвращает только их. Вы сохраняете их локально и обновляете время последнего обновления.

Если нужно обновлять без перезапуска, то при появлении новых данных, сервер отправляет пуш нотификейшн. Приложение принимает его и инициирует обновление также, как и в первом случае.

Comment: на сервере при помощи чего это можно реализовать? можете подсказать? сервер реализован на java + spring framework